# How to persist sessions with Jetty 7 and jetty-maven-plugin?

Tags: jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I'd like to configure Jetty to persist sessions on disk, so that restarting Jetty would not lose the sessions, but by reading the documentation I haven't yet got it working.

I'm running Jetty using [Jetty Maven plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin) (`org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin 7.4.3.v20110701`).

[Enabling Persistence for the Maven Jetty Plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Persisting_Sessions) tells to set up the `HashSessionManager` in the `sessionHandler` configuration section of the plugin, but the example there seems to be for the old `maven-jetty-plugin`, not the new `jetty-maven-plugin`.

I tried fixing the class names there like this (I also had to add a dependency to jetty-server jar, otherwise I got ClassNotFoundExceptions):

```
<webAppConfig implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyWebAppContext">
    <defaultsDescriptor>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/webdefault.xml</defaultsDescriptor>
    <contextPath>${jetty.contextRoot}</contextPath>
    <sessionHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler">
        <sessionManager implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager">
            <storeDirectory>${basedir}/target/jetty-sessions</storeDirectory>
        </sessionManager>
    </sessionHandler>
</webAppConfig>
```

Directory target/jetty-sessions gets created when server is run, but nothing is written there and the sessions don't persist as far as I can tell.

So, what am I missing?

Comment: I updated the eclipse.org wiki page to match the new plugin classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation lists the wrong class names. Use this snippet:

```
<sessionHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler">
  <sessionManager implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager">
    <storeDirectory>${basedir}/target/sessions</storeDirectory>
    <idleSavePeriod>1</idleSavePeriod>
  </sessionManager>
</sessionHandler>
```

I don't have an Eclipse login to fix it on their wiki. Maybe you can grab one and fix it there too to help others.

Update: I added `idleSavePeriod` to the configuration. I first thought you just copied the typo from Eclipse wiki.

Comment: Umm... Isn't that exactly what I already have in the question?

Comment: I made some seemingly non-related changes in the pom and suddenly noticed that the session was persisted. This was before I added the idleSavePeriod setting, but that certainly makes then appear faster in the storeDirectory. I still don't know why they didn't persist before and why they do now. Might have something to do with not everything being Serializable in the session earlier.

Comment: i hade some problems too with it. Sometimes it stores sessions, sometimes not. If something is not serializable i get errors. but if everything is serializable, nothing shows up in my session store. strange... maybe its just broken